# Microsoft SQL Server fails to load a simple CSV file

Tags: sql-server, database, csv, bcp

Here's how I set up the schema:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U <user> -P <pw> -d <relation> -Q "CREATE TABLE vehicle_reg (record_type varchar, vin varchar, registration_class varchar, city varchar, state varchar, zip int, county varchar, model_year int, make varchar, body_type varchar, fuel varchar, unladen_weight int, max_gross_weight int, passengers int, reg_valid_date date, reg_expiration_date date, color varchar, scofflaw varchar, suspension varchar, revocation varchar);"
```

To test this out, my CSV file contains exactly 1 line:

```
VEH ,5NMSGDAB5AH372379,PAS,ALEXANDRIA BAY ,NY,13607,JEFFERSON   ,2010,HYUND,SUBN,GAS     ,3875,,,06/26/2017,07/06/2019,WH   ,N,N,N
```

Here's how I issue the `bcp` command:

`bcp <db> in one-line.csv -S localhost -U <user> -P <pw> -d <relation> -n -t','`

But it simply doesn't copy anything:

```
Starting copy...

0 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 1
```

If I instead supply the full CSV file, I get 
`Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file`.

Any hints?

Comment: Does the file have a line terminator - try adding a blank line.. Also, have you tried to load the file using the wizard to check that it does load?

Comment: It doesn't have a blank line (wc -l gives 1) but I manually verified that it does have a proper Unix line terminator \n.  I am not sure what the "wizard" is.

Comment: In MS SQL Server Management Studio there is a wizard to transfer data. Also, the error message is clear - it does not like the EOF file marker; try different line endings or insert a blank line.

Comment: @Covi I'm pretty sure that MS SQL expects a Windows new-line character (\r\n)

Comment: The docs say you need to use `-r '0x0A'` to do what you want. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

If your file contains lines that are terminated with \n, then you need to tell BCP to look for \n as the line terminator. This is accomplished with the -r option. When the -r option is not included, BCP will default to a \r\n row terminator (carriage return and line feed). In your 1 line test file, BCP finds no line terminated with a \r\n and so loads nothing. Just make sure row terminators match up between what is in the file and what BCP is looking for.